# What's the measure of the segment $HD$ in triangle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:  In the triangle $ABC$ inscribed in a circle of diameter $AD$. Calculate $HD$ since $H$ is the orthocenter and the distances from the circumcenter to sides $AB$ and $AC$ are $2.5$ and $1.5$ respectively with $\angle BAC=60^o$ (Answer:$\sqrt{19}$)

My progress and relationships I found:

$\triangle AOE \sim \triangle ADC \implies
\frac{2R}{R} =\frac{AC}{AE} \therefore k = \frac{1}{2}\implies \\ 
DC = 2\cdot 1.5 = 3\\
Draw ~BD: \implies \triangle ABD \sim \triangle AGO\\
AO = AD \implies k = \frac{1}{2}\\
\therefore BD = 2\cdot OP = 2\cdot 2.5 = 5$

ABCD is cyclic

Draw $HD \rightarrow \triangle AHD\rightarrow HO$ is median $\implies$

T.Apollonius

$HD^2 +AH^2 = 2HO^2+\frac{R^2}{2}$

[image]

Comment: As you said $BD = 5$. Notice that $BH = 2OE = 3$ and $\angle HBD = 60^\circ$. Apply law of cosine.

Comment: or drop a perp from $D$ to $BF$. Say it meets $BF$ at $G$. Then $BG = 2.5, GH = 0.5$. $DG = 5 \sqrt3/2$. Now $HD^2 = 1/4 + 75/4 = 19$

Comment: @MathLover  One question. Wouldn't BG = BH+HG =3+0,5 = 3,5?
but BG =2,5???

Comment: @MathLover is it an error in the picture?

Comment: $G$ should be between $B$ and $H$ so yes the diagram is not accurate

Comment: @MathLover   thanks ..I will try to correct the diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MathLover hints:
$\mathsf{\triangle ABD \sim \triangle APO \implies
\frac{2R}{R} =\frac{BD}{PO} \therefore k = 2\\
\therefore BD = 2 \cdot OP = 2.2,5 = 5\\   
DG \perp FB (G \in FB)\\
\angle GBD = 60^o \implies GD = \frac{5\sqrt3}{2}~e~BG = \frac{5}{2}\\
(By~property)BH=2OE \therefore BH = 3\\
GH = BH-BG=3-2,5 \implies GH=\frac{1}{2} \\
T.Pit: \triangle DHG:HD^2 = GH^2+GD^2 \implies\\
HD^2 = \frac{75}{4} +(\frac{1}{2})^2 \therefore \boxed{\color{red}HD = \sqrt19}}$

[image]